# Segfault in libgstvideo shared library trying to stream video

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb, video-streaming, gstreamer

While trying to stream video using Gstreamer and its libraries, I encounter the following segfault in libgsvtvideo while converting the video format from RGB to NV12. Frame size is 921600 when collected in RGB format and NV12 I believe is 460800 bytes in size (half of RGB frame)

```
appsource:src[5702]: segfault at 7fc560028010 ip 00007fc56bd8ee63 sp 00007fc552181428 error 4 in libgstvideo-1.0.so.0.803.0[7fc56bd7a000+7c000]
```

I do not have the source code for libgstvideo on my machine so that makes it hard to debug.

I have attempted to use `debugger` but really all I get is a stack which is of no use since I cannot seem to load the debug symbols -

```
   Thread 79 "appsource:src" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7efd77a3f700 (LWP 5515)]
0x00007efe455d4e63 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007efe455d4e63 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0
#1  0x00007efe455dfc33 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0
#2  0x00007efe455dfdba in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0
#3  0x00007efe455e05c4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0
#4  0x00007efe455dfdba in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0
#5  0x00007efe455e0d2e in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0
#6  0x00007efe455dfdba in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0
#7  0x00007efe455e005b in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0
#8  0x00007efe45848509 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideoconvert.so
#9  0x00007efe455ee21e in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0
#10 0x00007efe48483ba5 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so.0
#11 0x00007efe48483446 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so.0
#12 0x00007efe496ec59f in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0
#13 0x00007efe496f4543 in gst_pad_push () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0
#14 0x00007efe4847ee55 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so.0
#15 0x00007efe4971ef31 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0
#16 0x00007efe487235ee in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#17 0x00007efe48722c55 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#18 0x00007efe51f776ba in start_thread (arg=0x7efd77a3f700) at pthread_create.c:333
#19 0x00007efe50a2541d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:109
```

I also attempted using `valgrind` to start my application but valgrind did not catch the segfault even thou it occurred.

Here is some of the relevant code that uses gstreamer in my application -

```
        snprintf( str_pipeline, sizeof( str_pipeline ), "appsrc name=appsource ! videoconvert ! " "video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,format=NV12,framerate=60/1 ! vaapih264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! " "udpsink host=%s port=5600", "xxx.xxx.x.x");

         pipeline = gst_parse_launch( str_pipeline, &gerror );

         if( pipeline )
         {
             appsrc = gst_bin_get_by_name( GST_BIN( pipeline ), "appsource" );
             app_caps = gst_caps_new_simple( "video/x-raw", "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "RGB", "width", G_TYPE_INT, 640, "height", G_TYPE_INT, 480, "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 60, 1, NULL );

             gst_app_src_set_caps( GST_APP_SRC( appsrc ), app_caps );

             g_object_set( G_OBJECT( appsrc ), "is-live", TRUE, "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME, NULL );

  gst_element_set_state( pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING );

            // get frame_buffer 

            GstBuffer *gstbuffer = gst_buffer_new_wrapped_full( ( GstMemoryFlags )0, frame_buffer, SIZE, 0, SIZE, NULL, NULL );
            g_signal_emit_by_name( appsrc, "push-buffer", gstbuffer, &ret );

            if (ret != GST_FLOW_OK)
            {     
               if ( debug )
                   printf( "error sending frame to gstreamer..: %d\n", ret );
            }
```

segfault occurs when I do the `g_signal_emit_by_name` I suppose.

I do have GST logs I collected by setting GST_DEBUG_FILE=6 and here is a snippet of the last few lines -

```
0:00:00.727642913  5968 0x7f547c226230 DEBUG               GST_META gstmeta.c:192:gst_meta_register: register "GstVideoMeta" implementing "GstVideoMetaAPI" of size 112
0:00:00.727666988  5968 0x7f547c226230 DEBUG             GST_BUFFER gstbuffer.c:2101:gst_buffer_add_meta: alloc metadata 0x7f547c235538 (GstVideoMeta) of size 112
0:00:00.727712527  5968 0x7f547c226230 LOG                videometa gstvideometa.c:305:gst_buffer_add_video_meta_full: plane 0, offset 0, stride 640
0:00:00.727731540  5968 0x7f547c226230 LOG                videometa gstvideometa.c:305:gst_buffer_add_video_meta_full: plane 1, offset 307200, stride 640
0:00:00.727752616  5968 0x7f547c226230 DEBUG             bufferpool gstbufferpool.c:240:mark_meta_pooled:<vaapivideobufferpool0> marking meta 0x7f547c235538 as POOLED in buffer 0x7f547c264850
0:00:00.727772579  5968 0x7f547c226230 DEBUG             bufferpool gstbufferpool.c:240:mark_meta_pooled:<vaapivideobufferpool0> marking meta 0x7f53b8001a48 as POOLED in buffer 0x7f547c264850
0:00:00.727791767  5968 0x7f547c226230 LOG               bufferpool gstbufferpool.c:282:do_alloc_buffer:<vaapivideobufferpool0> allocated buffer 0/0, 0x7f547c264850
0:00:00.727822443  5968 0x7f547c226230 DEBUG          basetransform gstbasetransform.c:1795:default_copy_metadata:<videoconvert0> copying metadata
0:00:00.727853207  5968 0x7f547c226230 LOG               GST_BUFFER gstbuffer.c:443:gst_buffer_copy_into: copy 0x7f547c264740 to 0x7f547c264850, offset 0-921600/921600
0:00:00.727881908  5968 0x7f547c226230 DEBUG          basetransform gstbasetransform.c:2157:default_generate_output:<videoconvert0> using allocated buffer in 0x7f547c264740, out 0x7f547c264850
0:00:00.727901871  5968 0x7f547c226230 DEBUG          basetransform gstbasetransform.c:2177:default_generate_output:<videoconvert0> doing non-inplace transform
0:00:00.727960085  5968 0x7f547c226230 LOG               GST_BUFFER gstbuffer.c:1649:gst_buffer_map_range: buffer 0x7f547c264740, idx 0, length -1, flags 10001
0:00:00.727981611  5968 0x7f547c226230 LOG               GST_BUFFER gstbuffer.c:212:_get_merged_memory: buffer 0x7f547c264740, idx 0, length 1
0:00:00.728010700  5968 0x7f547c226230 DEBUG                  vaapi gstvaapisurface.c:370:gst_vaapi_surface_new_full: size 640x480, format NV12, flags 0x00000000
0:00:00.728086865  5968 0x7f547c226230 DEBUG                  vaapi gstvaapisurface.c:210:gst_vaapi_surface_create_full: surface 0x4000008
0:00:00.728108203  5968 0x7f547c226230 DEBUG                  vaapi gstvaapiimage.c:248:gst_vaapi_image_new: format NV12, size 640x480
0:00:00.728141391  5968 0x7f547c226230 DEBUG                  vaapi gstvaapiimage.c:201:gst_vaapi_image_create: image 0xa000000
0:00:00.728194218  5968 0x7f547c226230 DEBUG        GST_PERFORMANCE gstvideoconvert.c:690:gst_video_convert_transform_frame:<videoconvert0> doing colorspace conversion from RGB -> to NV12
0:00:00.728214781  5968 0x7f547c226230 DEBUG        video-converter video-converter.c:2805:video_converter_generic: setup progressive frame
0:00:00.728237607  5968 0x7f547c226230 DEBUG        video-converter video-converter.c:538:get_border_temp_line: get temp line 0 (0x7f53b8001800 0)
0:00:00.728256133  5968 0x7f547c226230 DEBUG        video-converter video-converter.c:2518:do_unpack_lines: unpack line 0 (0) 0x7f53b8008030
```

I expect no segfault to occur and the frame to be streamed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't know anything about your frame buffer data. Where does it come from, what is it's lifetime? Note that `gst_buffer_new_wrapped` functions expect that the memory buffer belongs to the `GstBuffer` object after that call. So no other is allowed to delete/free this buffer anymore. Also - it is expected that the buffer can be freed via a call to `free()`. If that's is not given it is expected to crash. If this is not possible from your infrastructure you need to use `gst_buffer_new_allocate` and copy the data.

Comment: The frame buffers are gotten from using `rs_wait_for_frames()` and `rs_get_frame_data()`. They are stored internally inside the application and then from another process running in the same thread, gotten into frame_buffer , wrapped into Gstbuffer and sent to Gstreamer using the above code. I am not deleting/freeing the `Gstbuffer` anywhere currently.  Are you suggesting I copy frame_buffer into `gst_buffer_new_allocate` and use that to send to gstreamer instead ?

Comment: The GstBuffer will be freed by the GStreamer pipeline. However with the `wrapped` functions the GstBuffer takes ownership of the actual buffer data. If this buffer invalidates or gets reallocated by other means GstBuffer operated on invalid memory. So either you make sure it is ok that GstBuffer takes ownership of the data without anything else interfering - or you give it its own data buffer at the cost of a copy.

Comment: good point. That might be worth looking into. I am not sure how I would make sure how GstBuffer can take ownership without anyone else interfering. Any suggestions for that ?  And when you say give it its own data buffer, do I do that by using `gst_buffer_new_allocate()` ?

Comment: Yes, with `allocate` it gets its own memory buffer. You would then `fill` it with the buffer data you would have given into the `wrapped` style function. Which basically means it copies the data into the GstBuffer. Since then GstBuffer has its own buffer it doesn't matter if the original buffer pointer gets de-allocated or reused.

Comment: P.S. I normally use `gst_app_src_push_buffer` instead of that signal. Not sure if that makes a difference though - it is just that I have never used that.

Comment: where can I send you a beer ?

Comment: One more question. Is there a setting in gstreamer that would tell it to keep streaming a frame till the next frame is sent to it ? I do see some flickering in the video streaming and that is most likely because of the latency in my application (nothing much I do here) in sending the frames to gstreamer one after another. If Gstreamer can hold 1 frame till the next is sent to it and stream the next, that would reduce the flickering (I hope).

Comment: Thanks for the virtual beer ;) It depends what you are doing with the frame. Normally when you display it, it doesn't get cleared, only updated once a new frame arrives. If it clears/flickers for you it is probably related to the underlying GUI framework and or application that may be forcing a redraw of the drawing area.

Comment: Thanks! So sounds like I cant tell gstreamer to hold frame #1 and stream/display it till frame #2 is sent to it to stream/display. I am using QGC (Quad Ground Control for streaming btw if that helps)

Comment: Depends what you mean with "hold". Data flows. You can keep GstBuffers alive as long as you keep a reference to them (alive as in: information exist in your memory buffer). How and when this data gets drawn or redrawn on screen depends on your application, GUI framework, graphics interface and graphics drivers etc..

Comment: Makes sense. I will do some more experiments and get back to you. I am not doing anything to redraw or free any Gstbuffers if thats what you mean from within my application. Neither should QGC be doing anything to affect that. Perhaps, I am getting some blank frames from the camera (doubtful) once in a while that might be causing this flickering/blank screens ? I much appreciate your help.

Comment: I made some more code changes and the flickering is now gone! I lose about 10 frames when I stream more than 2500 frames so thats less than 0.5%. And thats with my application processing the frames. I think thats pretty good.